# half pyramid inverted with matrix pattern

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

how to create a half pyramid inverted with matrix pattern like this with loop?

### expected output

```
5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 3 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

**my code** like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            {
                int min = i < j ? i : j;
                System.out.print(N - min + 1 + " ");
            }
            for (int k = N-1; k >=1; k --) {
                System.out.print(k + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

}
```

and **my output** like this

```
5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 3 3 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 2 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Hint: take a piece of paper, and a pen, and then take a small N, like 3. And then *run* your code manually, yourself, without a computer. It is your homework. That step from "writing some first code" to "having code that really solves the problem" is the REAL part of your homework. Dont delegate that fun to others too early. Yes, learning programming is exactly that: sitting in front of your computer banging your head against the wall for HOURS. So: dont give up too early. Ask yourself: what are the *patterns* in the output, to derive RULES how to get there.

Comment: And note: your inner loops ALWAYS do the same number of print statements. That cant work. The inner loops need to print LESS, depending on where the outer loop is at!

Comment: Your logic looks too complicated, consider having two variables that are set to 5, one decrements in the outer loop.  If inner loop equal the decrement variable then print it more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested loops needs to be 3 deep:

1. Loop over the rows:

   ```
   5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1  ┐
   5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1    ┤
   5 4 3 3 3 2 1      ┤  Loop 1
   5 4 3 2 2 1        ┤
   5 4 3 2 1          ┘
   ```
2. Loop over the number values:

   ```
       ┌─────┬─┬─┬─┐     Loop 2
   ┌───┴───┐
   5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
   5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
   5 4 3 3 3 2 1
   5 4 3 2 2 1
   5 4 3 2 1
   └─┴─┴─┴─┘             Loop 2
   ```
3. Loop over the repeats of a number value:

   ```
       ┌─────...
   ┌─┬─┼─┬─┐             Loop 3
   5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
   5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
   5 4 3 3 3 2 1
   5 4 3 2 2 1
   5 4 3 2 1
   ```

Good luck coding that, since it looks like an assignment that you need to complete.

---

Since I can't leave a simple challenge like that alone, here is a solution. I added logic so it can handle pyramid sizes above 9, and then compressed the code to obscure it a bit.

```java
static void printHalfPyramidInverted(int n) {
    String f, fmt = " %" + Integer.toString(n).length() + "d";
    for (int k, j, i = n; i > 0; i--, System.out.println())
        for (f = fmt.substring(1), j = n; j > 0; j--)
            for (k = (i == j ? j : 1); k > 0; k--, f = fmt)
                System.out.printf(f, j);
}
```

*Output (size 5)*

```
5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 3 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

*Output (size 9)*

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 3 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

*Output (size 15)*

```
15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  5  5  5  5  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  4  4  4  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  3  3  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  2  1
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start constructing from bottom and notice how middle is changed (added `i` at `i` times).
Each line is assembled from right to left.(adapted properly on the end)
 Using additional data structure can make some task easier.

```
public class TestPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int N = 6;
         int next = N;
         List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
         {
            List<Integer> line=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j=1;j<=N;j++)
            {
                //middle
                if(next-N+2==j)
                {
                    for(int k=1;k<next-N+1;k++)
                    {
                        line.add(i);
                    }
                }
                
                line.add(j);
            }   
            if(i==N)
            {
                for(int k=1;k<next-N+1;k++)
                {
                    line.add(i);
                }
            }
            
            next++;
            
            String adaptedLine = line.stream().map(t->String.valueOf(t)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(adaptedLine);
            list.add(sb.reverse().toString());
            
         }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 5 4 3 2 1
6 5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 3 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Note: `If N>=10` then reverse line should be adapted properly since `10` is `01` in current version

```
String adaptedLine = line.stream().
                          sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).                         
                          map(t>String.valueOf(t)).
                          collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```